# Irreducible Curve (Variety)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to construct an irreducible variety of a plane curve. I would like it to be of the curve $f(x,y)=xy^s$, where s is an arbitrary integer. Since the ideal of this would be generated by one element, and that element a monomial, am I guaranteed that this is irreducible?

Comment: Dear violin.lover, I am not sure I understand the wording of your question. In algebraic geometry, a "variety" is just a variety, not a variety of something. The polynomial you wrote down defines a curve, but that curve is not irreducible, because the polynomial has distinct factors. (So in fact the situation is more or less the opposite of what you describe: any reduced monomial of degree bigger than 1 defines a reducible curve.)

Comment: If I have a polynomial in two variables over C, $(a_1x+b_1y)^r...(a_mx+b_my)^r_m$, I want to make it irreducible by adding some term (more than a constant). What would I need to add to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "the curve" $f(x,y)=xy^s$. Do you mean the zero set of the of $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb A ^2$? In that case, the ideal of the curve would be $I=\langle x \rangle \cap \langle y^s \rangle$, which is clearly not irreducible.

However, could it be that what you *really* mean is the image of $\mathbb A^1 \ni x \mapsto (x,x^s) \in \mathbb A^2$? In that case, the ideal is given by $I= (x^s-y)$, and this is certainly irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the polynomial $f(x,y) = xy^s$ to be an irreducible polynomial which isn't true ($x, y$ both divide $xy^s$).

Comment: "Intuitively, varieties that has a crossing will not be irreducible." This doesn't seem like such an accurate intuition to me. What about an irreducible nodal curve?

Comment: ah fair point - should I delete this part of leave it for posterity?

Comment: Dear Elden, that's your decision. My feeling is that it might cause some confusion for inexperienced readers.